# The tamid as well as the tamid in Rosh Hashana Musaf?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, nusach-ashkenaz, musaf

In the musaf amida of Rosh Hashana, at least in Nusach Ashkenaz, the list of the day's offerings concludes with the following two lines.

> ומנחתם ונסכיהם כמדבר שלשה עשרנים לפר ושני עשרנים לאיל ועשרון לכבש
> ויין כנסכו ושני שעירים לכפר ושני תמידים כהלכתם
>
> מלבד עלת החדש ומנחתה ועלת התמיד ומנחתה ונסכיהם כמשפטם לריח ניחח אשה לה

The second line is a quote from Numbers (from the same passage as the main list which has just come) and the first is a prayer-book formula similar to those in other musaf prayers.

These two lines as a pair sound jarring when read together, because they seem to mention the *tamid* twice. Jarring in particular because the referent of biblical "מלבד" seems to be transposed to the previous sentence instead of the verses which were quoted before that.

> "...and two tamids according to their rule. Apart from the new month offering and its meal-offering and the tamid and its meal offering..."

Are there any explanations of this paragraph which explicitly mention this oddity? Or have I misunderstood these words entirely? Or do any authorities suggest changing these words?

Comment: Just to clarify - the problem is that the first sentence says שני תמידים כהלכתם, and the second says עלת התמיד?

Comment: Exactly. Those two phrases seem to mean the same thing, but the word מלבד is acting between them.

Comment: @doniel not just עולת התמיד. It says "besides" the Tamid. Sounds like three tamids.

Comment: Jeremy if you can try checking the Machzor Mesoret Harav. I'd guess R Soloveitchik was bothered by this

Answer (score 1):

The copy I was using offered those lines as alternate versions, to say one or the other. I'm guessing that that's how it started and then the alternateness was forgotten about.

Comment: Do you know which edition that is? Thanks